# android restlet add non-standard header param

Tags: java, android, parameters, header, restlet

How I can add Header params in restlet android?

I have following code:

```
ClientResource clientResource = null;
try {
    clientResource = new ClientResource(jsonRestHelper.getUrl());
    for (Parameter parameter : jsonRestHelper.getParameters()) {
        //here works perfectly, jsonRestHelper is a helper class
        clientResource.addQueryParameter(parameter);
    }
    //here I wanna add headers param example
    //addHeader("Key","Value");
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Restlet doesn't have a simple generic method like addHeader("Key", "Value").  Instead, it has a variety of objects and properties attached to the Request and Response objects, which you use to specify what you want.  Which specific header or headers do you want to set?
By the way, if you have the Restlet in Action eBook, appendix E outlines how various headers map to Restlet objects and properties.

Comment: But how to I'll put a header that is not among the patterns rastlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to add custom (i.e. non-standard) headers?  If so, try this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import org.restlet.data.Form;
import org.restlet.engine.header.Header;
import org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderConstants;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.util.Series;


...

clientResource = new ClientResource("http://someurl.com");
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> attrs = clientResource.getRequest().getAttributes();
Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) attrs.get(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
    Series<Header> prev = (Series<Header>) 
        attrs.putIfAbsent(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, headers);
    if (prev != null) { headers = prev; }
}
headers.add("myHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");
```

Comment: Sorry, the request comes from ClientResource.getRequest().  I've updated my code snippet above.

Comment: Hmm, hold on a sec, getting a weird error while testing this.

Comment: I get a error:06-04 11:37:10.447: W/System.err(430): Communication Error (1001) - Error while processing a connection
06-04 11:37:10.447: W/System.err(430):  at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:627)
06-04 11:37:10.447: W/System.err(430):  at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:236)
06-04 11:37:10.447: W/System.err(430):  at $Proxy5.retrieve(Native Method)

Comment: Some things changed at some point and Restlet now uses Series<Header> instead of Form for setting headers.  I've tested the (now corrected) code above and it's working for me.  Sorry for the confusion.  BTW, this code was copied from something Thierry Boileau wrote at http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/How-to-set-response-header-tp7270489p7270784.html.

Comment: @AndyDennie can you please share library link for org.restlet.engine.header.Header

Comment: @SenthilMg, not sure exactly what you're looking for.  General info about the Restlet framework is [here](http://www.restlet.org/).  Javadoc for org.restlet.engine.header.Header (for the Android edition of Restlet) is [here](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/android/engine/org/restlet/engine/header/Header.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use Below code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String getURL = "rest url";
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
get.setParams(HttpParams parmams)
get.setHeader("Key","valye"); // Request Header
    try {
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
   } 
   catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The OP asked how to do this using Restlet.

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this older question but is there a way to add a custom header in restlet 1.1 where there client resource obj reference does not exist?